Multi-architecture docker image with Python / Selenium / Chrome or Firefox
I'm trying to install selenium / chromedriver on my Python image for an app. I've tried many different iterations, but nothing seems to work.
requirements.txt
selenium==4.23.1
webdriver-manager==4.0.2

I'm on Apple silicon. This is my Dockerfile. It's a bit of a mess now, because I've added all kinds of dependencies as nothing seems to have worked.
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    unzip \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    libnss3 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxi6 \
    libxtst6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libasound2 \
    libpango1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libxss1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    --no-install-recommends

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb || true
# Fix broken dependencies (if any)
RUN apt-get -f install -y

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

Build the image, start the container:
docker build . -t my-image
docker run -it --shm-size=2g my-image

In the Python shell:
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.84)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x555555daa81a <unknown>
#1 0x555555a78e50 <unknown>
#2 0x555555a60e20 <unknown>
#3 0x555555a5eb11 <unknown>
#4 0x555555a5f31f <unknown>
#5 0x555555a799f1 <unknown>
#6 0x555555a4de89 <unknown>
#7 0x555555a4d7d6 <unknown>
#8 0x555555af99db <unknown>
#9 0x555555af8e66 <unknown>
#10 0x555555aed233 <unknown>
#11 0x555555abb093 <unknown>
#12 0x555555abc09e <unknown>
#13 0x555555d71a7b <unknown>
#14 0x555555d75a31 <unknown>
#15 0x555555d5d645 <unknown>
#16 0x555555d765a2 <unknown>
#17 0x555555d4281f <unknown>
#18 0x555555d99618 <unknown>
#19 0x555555d997e2 <unknown>
#20 0x555555da960c <unknown>
#21 0x2aaaab7ab134 <unknown>


Try to add these dependencies to the dockerfile:
xvfb \
fonts-liberation \
libappindicator3-1 \
xdg-utils \

If still not working, can be good to see the logs by adding this configuration to the chrome driver:
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--v=1")


The core issue was that I was building an image for linux/amd64 (to match my cloud env) on Apple silicon (arm64, local machine).
Building worked, but the image didn't run as expected locally as evidenced by the error I posted. According to my research some things run, but I suspect running Chrome was too much.
It turns out, to handle my scneario Method 3 here is the way to go: https://www.izumanetworks.com/blog/build-docker-on-apple-m/
I ended up with the following Dockerfile. Note, I also switched to Firefox as Chrome is not packaged for arm64. This image now runs as expected both on Intel and Apple silicon.
# Stage 1: Build with cross-compilation support
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM tonistiigi/xx AS xx

# Main image
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM python:3.12-slim

# Install xx scripts
COPY --from=xx / /

# Use xx-apt-get for target-aware package installation
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN xx-apt-get update && \
    xx-apt install firefox-esr -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Python and application setup
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

